# Run Photoshop CC through wine

Tags: wine, winetricks, photoshop

I have a version of Photoshop CC installed on a Windows partition, but when run through wine, I get this error:

[image]

I've tried migrating the install over to my wine drive_c, but running the photoshop from there returns the same error message. Any tips?

Comment: You have to open `winecfg` (run from terminal) and set the Windows version to Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Open `winecfg` (run from terminal) and set the Windows version to Windows 7.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please click the checkmark to mark the answer as the solution.